# Can not export animation that is not skeletal animation to Ogre

Tags: animation, export, armature

There are some animation in my .blend and there is no armature in it. So the animation in it is not skeletal.

I used "OgreDotScene Exporter" tool and NLA Hijacking to export my .blend into .mesh and .scene for Ogre using. But what I got is just .mesh.xml(can convert to .mesh) that not included animation.

Dose the "OgreDotScene Exporter" tool can only export skeletal animations? How can I export my animation mentioned above?

Comment: What are the requirements for ogre? http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=70950

Comment: @stacker Do you mean I need to add skeleton to my mesh?

Comment: No, I mean you should first learn about the Ogre requirements and ask here only the Blender related things if you have problems to fulfill the requirements.